# How to call an image on touch event on android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, touch

I would like to know how to display an image when touching the screen.

**please note:** that I want the image to appear on the X/Y coordinates which I touch.

Answer (score 0):

Add an onTouch listener to the current view (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) and in the onTouch method add to an array (or arraylist etc) a custom object with variables of the image you want as well as the x/y coordiantes from the touch event (event.getX() , event.getY()).

e.g.

```
class Enemy{
    public Image image;
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Enemy(Image i, int x, int y){
        this.image=i;
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }
}
```

Then ovveride the onDraw method for your view and add a loop which goes through the arraylist and draws the picture on the view e.g.

```
for (Enemy e : enemies) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(e.image, e.x, e.y, null);
}
```

Comment: thanks! but how do I load the image on eclipse? and what should I do to make the image appear on touch?

Comment: Put an image in your drawable folder and use this code to load it. canvas.drawBitmap is the method to make it appear. see above.      Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);